# Embedding the video from watch link

Tags: php, database, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have many video links in database. I want the most viewed video to be embedded.I have this code to embed the youtube video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $songs[0]->link;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`$songs[0]->link` is the most viewed link of the video from database. It appears for e.g. as 
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx3EQQQ6yjM` while the embed link will be `https://www.youtube.com/embed/qx3EQQQ6yjM` so i need to make the watch link to embed link. How can this be done?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change different part using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
<?php echo str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $songs[0]->link);?>
```